# Why I am getting the Unable to cast exception here

Tags: c#, oop

Here is the code:

```
interface IA
{
}

interface IC<T>
{
}

class A : IA
{
}

class CA : IC<A>
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IA a;
        a = (IA)new A();    // <~~~ No exception here

        IC<IA> ica;

        ica = (IC<IA>)(new CA()); // <~~~ Runtime exception: Unable to cast object of type 'MyApp.CA' to type 'MyApp.IC`1[MyApp.IA]'.
    }
}
```

Why am I getting the casting exception in the last line of the code ?

Comment: `CA` doesn't implement `IC<IA>`.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, yes, you're right, it doesn't do it explicitly. But it does implement IC<A>, where A implements IA. I am curious, why the compiler passes this fine, but runtime gives me the exception.

Comment: Is this a co-variance problem?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `IC` as `interface IC<out T>` for the cast to work. This tells the compiler that `IC<A>` can be assigned to a variable of type `IC<IA>`.

See, [this page](http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    interface IPerson
    {
    }

    //Have to declare T as out
    interface ICrazy<out T>
    {
    }

    class GTFan : IPerson
    {
    }

    class CrazyOldDude : ICrazy<GTFan>
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            IPerson someone;
            someone = (IPerson)new GTFan();    // <~~~ No exception here

            ICrazy<GTFan> crazyGTFanatic;
            ICrazy<IPerson> crazyPerson;

            crazyGTFanatic = new CrazyOldDude() as ICrazy<GTFan>;

            crazyGTFanatic = (ICrazy<GTFan>)(new CrazyOldDude());

            crazyPerson = (ICrazy<IPerson>)crazyGTFanatic;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that would set `ica` to null, so it doesn't help much.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Oh, so you're saying that ica will never ever be not null?  Regardless, you are correct as it _is_ null if you use my suggestion.

Comment: Yes, cause the cast is not valid and hence the `as` operator will return null.