# InvalidCastException, may involve generics

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following classes:

```
public interface IA
{
}

public class A : IA
{
}

public interface IB<T> where T : IA
{
    Foo SomeMethod(T someObject);
}

public abstract class BBase<T> : IB<T> where T : IA
{
    // implements SomeMethod();
}

public class BSpecific: BBase<A>
{
    // overrides SomeMethod();
}
```

This throws an exception at runtime:

```
var foo = ((IB<IA>)Activator.CreateInstance("BSpecific"));
```

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type BSpecific to type IB'1[IA]

Casting to BBase throws the same exception.

[Why I am getting the Unable to cast exception here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762252/why-i-am-getting-the-unable-to-cast-exception-here) is a very similar scenario, but the recommended answer (use contravariance/"out T") doesn't work for my situation because of SomeMethod() which takes a parameter of T.

I'm not really sure why I would need contravariance (or what contravariance does exactly). The type and class are both being cast to an interface they implement, so...?

Is there something else I can do?

(The code containing the cast is used as a reference by the project containing the `BSpecific` class, but itself has no knowledge of what a `BSpecific` is, so the cast is mandatory.)

Comment: Did you try IB<IA> foo = Activator.CreateInstance("BSpecific") as IB<IA>; ? Is foo null? Maybe you should provide full class name like: "Namespace.BSpecific"? Or maybe you should try create a Type using Type.GetType("BSpecific") and then using this type in activator?

Comment: did you try it (the out things)? it looks like your SomeMethod accepting the T as function parameter, it doesn't relate to the interface's T or base class 's T

Comment: @AdamJachocki It's null, and setting a breakpoint tells me that an instance of BSpecific is correctly made but then the cast fails.

Comment: @SKLTFZ I tried it and a compile time error shows up on SomeMethod() because T "must be contravariantly valid but is covariant".

Comment: There's no safe way to do this cast - `BSpecific` implements `IB<A>` so it's `SomeMethod` method accepts only instances of `A`, not any `IA` instance.

Answer (score 1):

`BSpecific` inherits from `BBase<A>` and not `BBase<IA>`.

Either make `BSpecific` inherit from `BBase<IA>` or cast `BSpecific` to `IB<A>` and your code will compile.

Comment: But A implements IA? Also, both of these require this code to know what a BSpecific or an A is at compile time, which I'm trying to avoid. This is used as a dependency by the application that implements the abstract classes and interfaces, so what BSpecific or A is depends on the use case.

Comment: Are you sure you can't make `BSpecific` inherit from `BBase<IA>`?